# My php jquery ajax form request sometimes fire twice, maybe 2 out of 10 request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

Below is my code to submit the form.
`8` out of `10` request sent works fine, while the others fires twice or thrice and yet return a single response for sweet alert display.

I make use of sweet alert confirmation before sending request so as to be sure of not clicking twice the submit button before processing.

Yet the issue persist, kindly assist further

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','#userForm',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var subscriptio = $('#subscription option:selected').text();
        var subscripti = $('#product option:selected').text();
        swal.fire({
            title: 'Dear  $username',
            text: 'Should we process your ' +subscriptio+ ' request?',
            icon: 'question',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Continue',
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value){
                var data = $('#user_form').serialize();
                console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    data: data,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'action.php',
                    cache: false, 
                }).done(function(data){  
                    psrt();
                    $('#security').val('');
                    var dataResult = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (dataResult.status=='successful'){ 
                        swal.fire(dataResult.status, dataResult.message, dataResult.icon);
                    }else {
                        swal.fire(dataResult.status, dataResult.message, dataResult.icon); 
                    }     
                }).fail(function(){
                    swal.fire('Oops!', 'Something went wrong, kindly contact Admin', 'error'); 
                });
            } 
        }) 
    }); 
</script>
```

// **My actions.php code** all variables used inside the function postrayer are correctly declared without any error
*//$wizz is an array of numbers exploded for verification*

```
  $mobiler = isset($_POST['mobile']) ? isints($_POST['mobile']) : '';
  $mobile = in_array($mobiler, $wizz)? false :$mobiler;
```

*//Code to declined and **exit** with response if $mobile.is false is declared here*

```
$postrayer = begins($userid, $wallet, $chan, $mypin,  $mobile, $amountsplit);  

If ($postrayer){           
    *//apiFunction is a function to send http request and it is being declared below*

    function apiFunction ($url,$payload,$token){

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);  

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $headers = [

             "Authorization:$token",

            'Content-Type: application/json'

        ];

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $dataapi = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        

        return $dataapi;
    }

    $fg = apiFunction ($url,$payload,$token);
    $api_result = json_decode($fg,true);
    if(!empty($api_result)){
        If($api_result['Status'] == 'successful' ){
            // I echo my result to sweet alert
        }
    }  
}
```

8 out of 10 form request will work perfectly, but the remaining will send request twice or thrice

I can't monitor this from the network tab because it seldomly happens and I don't know when precisely it will.

And this is for transactional purpose

Please help

Comment: Could you please indent that code halfway properly, so that we can see what belongs into which block, more easily.

Comment: For those who don't know, and that will probably be most of us, [sweet alert](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2) is a piece of software.

Comment: Have you observed this behaviour yourself while using the application, or just from reports by other users? If you see it yourself, you should be able to use your Javascript debugger, plus some console logging and tracking of the originator of network requests, to see if the AJAX requests are being triggered multiple times, and how.

Comment: _"while the others fires twice or thrice"_ - which you notice how/at what point, exactly? _"and yet return a single response for sweet alert display."_ - so are you saying that you are neither getting the alert from the `if (dataResult.status=='successful')` nor the else branch, and not that from the `fail` handler either? Unless you are getting any errors at that point that prevent your client-side code from executing any further, I would doubt that those additional requests were actually caused by this AJAX code to begin with.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, I recorded all transactions with their API response returned with timestamp into the database, it is from here I noticed how many times the form requests at each point where fired. I can't monitor this from the network tab because it seldomly happens and I don't know when precisely it will. **From my code, I parsed API response and catch if it is successful or not so as to display to end user. And this works fine. Either it was fired one or twice, the sweet alert displays just one response for either failed or successful transaction**

Comment: Hm. That's tricky. Is there any way that `action.php` could be being called, aside from this AJAX request here? Or any way that the URL in `$url` could be called from elsewhere? Just need to rule out all possibilities, and attempt to find the source of the duplication.

Comment: @adyson No, the form id appears throughout the website only being called once and straight to the action.php and vice versa. Both the id and the url is not repeated anywhere within the entire website

Comment: I checked the logs on the server and discovered that the double request comes from the page where I placed my ajax jquery code and sent the post request to action at different timestamp pace. Please any help, will using .One() instead of .On() event call solve this issue. The problem is definitely not from double click nor page refresh, because I have completely taken care of that.